# Iterate through dynamic Result Set

Tags: java, list, hashmap, iteration, resultset

My query can return dynamic number of columns from a table. I need to iterate through each column and store data for all the rows of that particular column and store them in a list. I need to perform this for all columns returned from the query.
Again, the query can return dynamic columns.
What is the best way to achieve this above scenario, with least code complexity.
For example:

```
------------------
Employee Table
------------------
Name | Age | Roll
------------------
A    | 21  | 1
------------------
B    | 22  | 2
```

I need to first iterate through Name column and store Name as key and A and B as values for that map, then iterate through Age column and store Age as key and 21,22 as values for that key and so on...

I  want to achieve this with least complexity.

Here is the code which I have developed :

```
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

for (int j = 1; j <= columnsNumber; j++)
                {
                    String Colkey = rsmd.getColumnName(j);
                    List<String> colValueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        colValueList.add(rs.getString(Colkey));


                    }

                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    map.put(Colkey,colValueList);
                }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try do it by yourself? Include your code in question

Comment: `Map<Sting, List<String>>`, first string is column name and  the ``List<String>` holds the information of the columns

Comment: I want to achieve this functionality for tables which have huge data. So I am bothered about the complexity.

Comment: @ Lukasz_Plawny - Please find the code added.

Comment: XtremeBaumer : Can you kindly elaborate ? The code has been pasted for reference.

Comment: The loops should be swapped. External loop uses `rs.next()` but internal iterates throuhg the columns. Use `MultiValueMap` or `Map<String, List<String>>` adding values for column names

Comment: Can we achieve this using DynaBean concept ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this:

```
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

for (int j = 1; j <= columnsNumber; j++) {
    String Colkey = rsmd.getColumnName(j);
    map.put(Colkey, new ArrayList<String>());
}
while (rs.next()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> e: map.entrySet) {
        String Colkey = e.getKey();
        List<String> list = e.getValue();
        list.add(rs.getString(Colkey));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. When I implemented the above logic, the time taken was 41574 ms, compared to 211310 ms. This has met the complexity needs to some extent. However I wish I could get something which would be further least complex.

Answer (score 0):

It is Simple one.
Please follow the POJO concept while storing into the map values.
1.First get the table logical Structure and create the Pojo class like this:-

```
    public class Employee {

    String name;
    int age;
    int roll;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
}
```

Now the logic for the inserting in the HashMap.

```
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    HashMap map=new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    for (int j = 1; j <= columnsNumber; j++)
                    {
                        String Colkey = rsmd.getColumnName(j);
                        List<String> colValueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        while (rs.next())
                        {
                           Employee emp=new Employee();
                           emp.setAge(rs.getInt("AGE"));
                           emp.setAge(rs.getInt("ROLL"));
                           emp.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
                         map.put(emp.getName(), emp);
                        }

                        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                  }
```

Comment: Will this work for dynamic number of columns, keeping code complexity in mind ?